# SQL users ordering more than n products

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have started refreshing my SQL knowledge and trying to practice some challenges using [W3School schemas from this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in).
The problem I am trying to solve is "How to find customer id's from Order and OrderDetails table who has ordered more than 3 different product and group them in bucket of 3+, 10+ orders based on the number of orders they placed"

My effort:

```
select  Distinct(o.CustomerID),
  case
    when count (Distinct (od.OrderID)) >= 0 and count (Distinct (od.OrderID)) <= 1 then '0 - 1'
    when count (Distinct (od.OrderID)) >= 2 and count (Distinct (od.OrderID)) <= 4 then '3-4'
    else 'no match'
  end As NumOrd
 from Orders o 
 join OrderDetails od 
 where o.OrderID = od.OrderID 
 group by od.OrderId 
 having count (od.OrderID) > 1;
```

syntax error or W3School which is not clearly saying what is wrong and is my approach correct?

Update:
As soon as I add second case statement I get syntax error or W3School which is not clearly saying what is wrong -> This corrected based on @Gordon comment. 
However now all the records are going into first bucket even if there are Customers that ordered more than 3 times.

Based on comments adding more details:
If you see below queries output I see CustomerId 7 and 10 ordered 4 different order and customer 5 ordered 3 orders. I want to create buckets (0-3,4-6, 6-10) on the basis of number of orders they place.

```
select  distinct(o.CustomerID) from Orders o join OrderDetails od where o.OrderID = od.OrderID group by od.OrderId having count (od.OrderID) > 1;
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `case`.  You have one case EXPRESSION with multiple conditions.

Comment: Opps that was really stupid from me, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Be aware that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `group by o.CustomerID` and in the `CASE` expression there are only 2 cases that you should check because in the `having` clause you make sure that only customers with at least 3 orders are returned:

```
select 
  o.CustomerID,
  case 
    when count(distinct od.OrderID) between 3 and 9 then '3+'
    when count(distinct od.OrderID) >= 10 then '10+'
  end NumOrd
from Orders o inner join OrderDetails od 
on o.OrderID = od.OrderID 
group by o.CustomerID 
having count(distinct od.OrderID) >= 3
```

Also you mention in your question that the requirement is:

> to find customer id's from Order and OrderDetails table who has
>   ordered more than 3 different **products**

So maybe instead of counting `OrderID`s you should count `ProductID`s and you must change to:

```
count(distinct od.ProductID)
```

Comment: count(distinct od.ProductID) -> This makes sense as one order can have multiple products.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked

> who has ordered more than 3 different product and group them in bucket of 3+, 10+ orders based on the number of orders they placed

We should use next query:

```
select
    o.CustomerID, -- get CustomerID
    count(Distinct(ProductID)) ProductsCount, -- calculate different products count
  case
    when count(Distinct(o.OrderID)) > 10 then '10+'
    when count(Distinct(o.OrderID)) > 3 then '3+'
    else '1+'
  end As NumOrd -- calculate bucket by orders count
 from Orders o 
 join OrderDetails od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
 group by o.CustomerID
 having ProductsCount > 3; -- filter out customers with less them 3 different products
```